# Accessing variable value from index.js to another js file on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to nodejs and I have `index.js` file which is called when I start my nodejs express server using nodemon index command.
In this `index.js` file I am connecting to google drive and getting `jwtClient` object when the connection is successful.
I want to use this `jwtClient` object in `product.js` file to upload image to google drive.
In `index.js` file once I have value in `jwtClient` variable I am doing `module.exports = jwtClient;`
and I am accessing `jwtClient` in `product.js` as `const jwtClient = require('../index');`
which is not working.
What are the ways I can access jwtClient in product.js from index.js without creating new object and having the same object reference.

In index.js file:

```
// configure a JWT auth client
let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']);
//authenticate request
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully connected to gdrive!");
    }
});

module.exports = jwtClient;
```

In product.js file

```
const jwtClient = require('../index');
```

Comment: What isn't working? Is the problem that it's not authorized in time?

Comment: I am getting value of jwtClient as { }  in product.js file but the value of jwtClient is not { } in index.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was exporting literal instead of Object. So the code `module.exports = jwtClient;` exports literal but jwtClient is object so I used `exports.jwtClient = jwtClient;` in `index.js` file and then I access it in `product.js` file as

`const index = require('../index.js');`
`console.log(index.jwtClient);`

reference https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that when you examine your `jwtClient` variable, the `jwtClient.authorize` did not execute yet. Make sure that in `product.js` file you wait till it happen. The easyest (but not best) way to do that is

```
const jwtClient = require('../index/jwtClient');

setTimeout(function() {
  console.dir(jwtClient);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: If I am exporting var var1=5; module.exports = var1; as well as var var2=9; module.exports = var2; in index.js file and then I want to access it in product.js file will const xyz = require('../index'); have value of var1 or var2?

Comment: In the example that you mention, you'll likely to have exported value of var2

Comment: However, because of asynchronous nature of NodeJS, the order of executioin is: 1) `new google.auth.JWT`, 2) `module.exports = jwtClient;`, 3) `jwtClient.authorize`. That's because `authorize` is an asynchronous action that takes time to execute